# HCl/diethyl ether + Nitrogen?

Tags: solutions, purification

Just wondering if anyone can tell me why bubbling nitrogen through a solution of $\ce{HCl}$/diethyl ether catalyst would remove said mix from my solution.

My current thought is that the $\ce{N2}$ will form ammonia and deprotonate the $\ce{HCl}$. But what of the Diethyl ether? I can't think of how it would be removed.

My only final explanation is that it is the $\ce{HCl}$ which is the important species to remove and the diethyl ether is just solvent ... but I would really like a second opinion!

Comment: N2 is not going to convert into ammonia from contact with HCl.  Nitrogen is very unreactive stuff.  The removal is as ron described, a purely physical process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HCl is a gas at room temperature and diethyl ether is a low boiler.  Both will have significant vapor pressures and, therefore, exist in the vapor phase above your  solution.  The HCl and diethyl ether in solution will continuously maintain an equilibrium with the vapor phase. As you bubble nitrogen through the system it will continuously sweep the vapor out, removing HCl and diethyl ether.  But since the HCl and diethyl ether in solution continuously maintain an equilibrium in the vapor phase, they will be continuously swept out until all of the HCl and diethyl ether in solution have been removed.